# Make the element appear at the end of the arc

Tags: html, d3.js, svg

I am trying to make the image appear at the end of the arc much like this:

[image]

but it appears in the middle. *So no matter if I set the end angle / start angle anything the image should always appear at the end of the arc*.

This is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wQXCL/421/

I know I have to use translate so something like:

```
.attr("transform", function(d) {

            var x = 200 * Math.cos(0.25 * Math.PI);
            var y = 200 * Math.sin(0.25 * Math.PI);

            return "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")";

        });
```

But this formula is not working as well.

Comment: the formula is wrong. you should have for x : centreX + radius * Math.cos(a), and for y  : centreY + radius * Math.sin(a), 'a' being the angle

Comment: I tried that as well and yet not working. Can you update the jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/wQXCL/423/

Here is the formula for points on a circle :

```
x = cx + r * cos(a)
y = cy + r * sin(a)
```

So in your fiddle (you dont need to add the center here as you're already there, i think D3 makes the arc around the point of translation. So you are at point 200/100 as you translated there previously. So the center you need to add to the formula is 0,0) :

```
var x =  60* Math.cos(0.25 * Math.PI)
var y =  60* Math.sin(0.25 * Math.PI)
```

The problem with this is, D3 arc starts at 90 degrees (i.e 3 o'clock). So you have to take that away (`Math.PI/2`). You also have to take care of the image size :

```
var x =  60* Math.cos(0.25 * Math.PI - (Math.PI/2)) -8 ; // take away half the width of the image
var y =  60* Math.sin(0.25 * Math.PI - (Math.PI/2)) -8 ;
```

The value of `60` is the center of the inner and outer radius as you want the image in the center of both :)

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks. Amazing. But how did you take value 60 as cx and cy? Height and width of svg is 400 thus shouldn't it be 200 as cx and cy?

Comment: You dont have to add the center as you are already there, that value is the radius (the center of inner and outer). I have updated another fiddle thats more precise, not using the -8 at the end but editing the multiplication inside the brackets : http://jsfiddle.net/wQXCL/425/ So it rotates the image back around the arc slightly rather than translating :)

Comment: Thanks. The most confusing part was I had to subtract Math.PI/2. I am a beginner in D3JS. Where can i find these things?

Comment: To be honest im not sure. I found out the problem myself when working with this a while back. May be down to D3, SVG, or probably the coordinate system the algorithm uses ? Im not 100% :(